# 開発環境とサーバ環境のdllのversion違いを吸収するには？

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, oracle, iis

当該環境はいくつかのdllに分かれており、修正対象となったdllだけ載せ替えて機能の修正を行いたいのですが、サーバ環境へ作成したdllをdeployしたところ以下のようなerrorが発生しました。

```
ファイルまたはアセンブリ 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'、またはその依存関係の 1 つが読み込めませんでした。指定されたファイルが見つかりません。
```

原因としては、開発環境で使っていたOracle.DataAccessのversionとサーバ環境のversionに差異があったためだと思っています。

とりあえず、実行環境のversionを把握して、同versionを開発環境に入れてbuildすれば良いのだと思うのですが...仮に、そのversionが提供されなくなったら？という不安がよぎります。
そこで質問なのですが、開発環境と実行環境でOracle.DataAccessのversionが違っても実行時にerrorが発生しないようにできるのでしょうか？
サーバ環境の変更は許容されないと思うため、開発環境側でなんとかできないかな？と思った次第です。

しばらく調べてるんですが、どのように対処するのが良いのか分からず、解法が見つかりません。
何か情報を提供いただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

**サーバ環境**
・Windows Server 2008R2
・IIS7
・ASP.NET .NET Framework 3.5
[image: サーバ環境assembly]

**開発環境**
・Windows 7 Professional (64bit環境)
・Visual Studio 2008 Professional
・IIS Express
・ASP.NET .NET Framework 3.5
[image: 開発環境assembly]

Comment: インストーラーを保存しておき、同じものを開発環境・サーバ環境へインストールするだけではありませんか？

Comment: すみません、情報が足りませんでした。当該モジュールはいくつかのdllに分かれており、修正対象となったdllだけ載せ替えて機能の修正を行いたいのです。また、サーバ環境の変更は許容されないと思うため、開発環境側でなんとかできないかな？と思った次第です。
また、管理などもまともに行われていないようで。。。その当時利用したインストーラなども保存されていない可能性も高いと思ったので、このような質問をさせていただきました。

Comment: ご質問の内容が技術的に出来たとしても、そもそも論ですが、開発環境と実行環境で食い違ったDLLのままテストしていては、テストの意味がないと思うのですが・・・。

Comment: 反応遅くなってしまいました。
yhataさんの仰るとおりです。bestはsayuriさんが書かれている通りで、環境に合ったinstallerを用意しておいて、それを使うことなんですが...残念ながらそのinstallerが無い状態でなんとかできないかと模索しています。
正直、できない事を質問しているような気はしているのですが...

Answer (score 1):

遅延バインディングですかねぇ。

参考URL:
http://urashita.com/archives/1760#C
http://ufcpp.net/study/csharp/sp4_dynamic.html#late_binding

WinFormsでExcelを扱う際に、複数バージョンのExcelに対応しようとして
遅延バインディングを使ったことがあります。
ASP.NETでも使えると思います。

ただ、遅延バインディングにするとVisual Studio上でIntelliSenceが効かなくなるので、
開発がちょっとやりづらくなりますね。

Comment: 遅くなりましたが、解答ありがとうございます。
この方法だと、build対象の既存コードで対象の部分を全て変えてやらないといけませんよね...

Answer (score 0):

開発環境では 2.112.3 をお使いで、実行環境では 2.112.1 をお使いだということですが、改修対象となっている新しい機能は 2.112.**3** に依存しているでしょうか (2.112.**1** では動かないことが明確ですか)。

もし**そうでない**ならば、Visual Studio のソリューション エクスプローラで今問題になっているプロジェクトの「参照」ノードを展開し、Oracle.DataAccess を選択して、プロパティ グリッドに表示される「特定バージョン」を False にしてみてください (Oracle.DataAccess は既定で True になっていると思います)。

[image: アセンブリ参照の設定]

画像では手元の PC に Visual Studio 2008 と Oracle DAC が入っていないので、Visual Studio 2015 上で System.Core に対する設定で例示していますが、Visual Studio 2008 上で Oracle.DataAccess に対してまったく同じ操作ができるはずです。

この方法は、改修対象のアプリケーションが古い DLL に合わせるパターンで、実行環境上の既存のアプリケーション群に迷惑をかけることはないはずです。

もし、改修対象のアプリケーションが 2.112.**3** に依存していて既存のアプリケーション群と改修対象のアプリケーションが**同じ bin フォルダに配置されていない**のであれば、先ほどの「特定バージョン」は True のまま、「ローカルにコピー」を True にしてみてください。

.NET のアプリケーションは外部アセンブリへの参照を解決する際に、自分の bin フォルダ内に合致するものがないかを調べるので、GAC 内のアセンブリとは違うバージョンのアセンブリを自分の bin フォルダに含める (「ローカルにコピー」する) ことで解決できる可能性があります。

もし既存のアプリケーションと bin フォルダを共有していたとしても、外部アセンブリの検索方法は config で変更できたと思います (うろ覚えですし、やったことはありません)ので、「プロービング (probe / probing)」をキーワードに調べてみてください。

Answer (score -1):

バージョンリダイレクトって機能があるので、それで動かせるんじゃないでしょうか
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx